# Identify patterns or sequences in list using python?

Tags: python

Given a long list, is there an algorithm or known approach to identifying patterns or repetitive sequences within a list?

For instance, given the following list:

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4 ...]
```

... it would return something like:

```
[1, 3, 5] appears 3 times
[1, 3, 5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[2, 4] appears 3 times
```

I have tried searching for an applicable algorithm or solution, such as prefixspan, but I don't know whether that is the correct approach.

Comment: how long is long? are there any other conditions? what is the actual goal state ... list all patterns that repeat at least 2x? find the longest pattern that repeats 2x+? find the pattern that repeats most frequently? `[2]` repeats 4x also, so why would that not be in the list?

Comment: Thousands to tens of thousands of items in a single list.  Ideally, I would like to define minimum pattern length using parameters.  E.g. find all patterns that are at least x items long.  I assume most patterns in the list will be less than 20 items.

Comment: i think you need full exploration which will take a while... or more rules to dial in on the haystack ... in your example wouldnt `[8,2]` also appear 2x? and really all sublists in `[1,3,5,8,2]` ? or because there is  one extra `[1,3,5]` without the `[8,2]` that is why its included but [8,2] is not? ... i think you will likely need to give us significantly more details about your problem statement and goal state...

Comment: Do overlapping occurrences count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive solution could be to use a [sliding window approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations


def get_repetitive_sequences(nums: list[int]) -> dict[tuple[int, ...], int]:
    sequences = Counter(
        tuple(nums[i:j + 1]) for i, j in combinations(range(len(nums)), 2))
    return {seq: count for seq, count in sequences.items() if count > 1}


nums = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4]
repetitive_sequences = get_repetitive_sequences(nums)
for seq, count in repetitive_sequences.items():
    print(f'{list(seq)} appears {count} times')
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3] appears 3 times
[1, 3, 5] appears 3 times
[3, 5] appears 3 times
[2, 4] appears 3 times
[1, 3, 5, 8] appears 2 times
[1, 3, 5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[3, 5, 8] appears 2 times
[3, 5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[5, 8] appears 2 times
[5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[8, 2] appears 2 times
```

If you want a more efficient solution, you could consider using the [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm):

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict, deque
from itertools import combinations


class Node:

    def __init__(self, parent=None, x=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.x = x
        self.children = {}
        self.failure_link = None
        self.output_links = set()


def build_trie(subsequences: list[tuple[int, ...]]) -> Node:
    root = Node()
    for subsequence in subsequences:
        node = root
        for x in subsequence:
            if x not in node.children:
                node.children[x] = Node(parent=node, x=x)
            node = node.children[x]
        node.output_links.add(subsequence)
    return root


def build_failure_links(root: Node) -> None:
    queue = deque([root])
    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        for x, child in node.children.items():
            if node == root:
                child.failure_link = root
            else:
                failure_node = node.failure_link
                while failure_node is not None and x not in failure_node.children:
                    failure_node = failure_node.failure_link
                if failure_node is None:
                    child.failure_link = root
                else:
                    child.failure_link = failure_node.children[x]
            child.output_links |= child.failure_link.output_links
            queue.append(child)


def get_repetitive_sequences(nums: list[int]) -> dict[tuple[int, ...], int]:
    subsequences = Counter(
        tuple(nums[i:j + 1]) for i, j in combinations(range(len(nums)), 2))
    root = build_trie(subsequences)
    build_failure_links(root)
    sequences = defaultdict(int)
    node = root
    for x in nums:
        while node != root and x not in node.children:
            node = node.failure_link
        if x in node.children:
            node = node.children[x]
        for subsequence in node.output_links:
            sequences[subsequence] += 1
    return {
        subsequence: count
        for subsequence, count in sequences.items() if count > 1
    }


nums = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4]
repetitive_sequences = get_repetitive_sequences(nums)
for seq, count in repetitive_sequences.items():
    print(f'{list(seq)} appears {count} times')
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3] appears 3 times
[3, 5] appears 3 times
[1, 3, 5] appears 3 times
[2, 4] appears 3 times
[5, 8] appears 2 times
[1, 3, 5, 8] appears 2 times
[3, 5, 8] appears 2 times
[1, 3, 5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[3, 5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[5, 8, 2] appears 2 times
[8, 2] appears 2 times
```